# Eclipse and Google Drive

Tags: eclipse, workspace, google-drive-api

My computer at home and my computer at work synchoronized with Google Drive. I created an Eclipse workspace and create an Android project at home. It's copied to my work computer. But I cant open the workspace at work with Eclipse. How can I open an existing workspace with the projects in it by using Eclipse?

Comment: What is the problem opening the workspace?

Comment: I open the work space with File > Switch Workspace > Other...
Eclipse restarts and I File > Import... the project in the workspace.
It says "Invalid project description. K:\Google Drive\Work\Java\MyProject overlaps the location of another project: 'MyProject'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When switching to the concerning workspace the project should already be contained as it belong to the workspace. So you don´t need to import the project. In fact importing causes the error you realize.

Probably you don't see the project at work because eclipse doesn´t find it on the path. So you could either make sure that the project (to your google drive and the project) is the same as at home then eclipse should find it. Or copy the project directly into the workspace by removing the project "at home" from the workspace and re-importing it. Choose the option "copy to my workspace" from the import dialog.